# Wind erosion of Ice

Tags: experimental-physics, ice

I saw this video on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hs5iXGJVkb8, but I really don't how answer this question:
How is it possible that wind can cause ablation of ice? I know that ice can ablate by sublimation or evaporisation, but how can we explain that wind can cause ice to ablate?

Comment: It's the material the  wind carries that performs the erosion. http://www.geo.fu-berlin.de/en/v/geolearning/mountain_building/weathering/Erosion/index.html. This is rock, not ice, but it's the same principle of carrying particles at sometimes high velocities. This is, imo, more Earth science SE than physics

Comment: The ice tag might be appropriate, but the other tags don't seem to fit the question, imo

Answer (score 0):

Temperature may play little role in the ablation process in the video. The strength of the wind is such that it shears off the ice/snow. The same as you blow off dust.